# How to check if a Kubernetes object is fully deleted?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to create an automated pipeline that would run multiple pods one after another on a namespace. The current issue is, between runs I want to wait for a pod to be fully deleted before running the next. Are there any ways to check if a given pod is fully deleted?

Current script:

```
kubectl delete -f pod.yaml
sleep 10
kubectl create -f pod.yaml
error when creating "pod.yaml": object is being deleted: pods "test-pod" already exists
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
kubectl delete -f pod.yaml
until kubectl get pod <pod-name> 2>&1 >/dev/null; do sleep 10; done
kubectl create -f pod.yaml
```

Basically, wait until `kubectl get pod <pod-name>` returns an error because it doesn't exist.

Comment: I know is too late, but what means -> pod <pod-name> 2>&1 >/dev/null; ty.

Answer (score 4):

In case you want to delete the pod immediately, use this.

```
kubectl delete pod NAME --grace-period=0 --force
```

Answer (score 3):

kubectl 1.11+ waits for the deletion to be completed before delete returns.

Answer (score 3):

Use `--wait` option, i.e.:

```
kubectl delete -f your.yaml --wait=true
```